# Why does "whence" have "when" in it?

Tags: etymology, adverbs

No definition or usage of *whence* relates to time, but to place.  One would therefore expect it to be some form of *where*, not of *when*.  What caused *when* to pertain to time, and *whence* to pertain to place?

Comment: Wherefore does *whence* have *when* in it, indeed?

Comment: Whence means "from where" or "from which" and there is no "when" inside of that word.

Comment: I agree with your first statement, and disagree with the second.

Comment: "When" means where in time. "Whence" means where in space. They are very closely related terms with very closely related meanings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Whennes* is the later (c1300) genitive of *Hwanone*, which according to the Online Etymological Dictionary is a related form of *hwaenne*, or the ancestor to *when*.

Genitives indicate *origin*, *place*, and *possession (or circumscripture)* of a noun.  According to the dictionary, the *-ce* is what indicates that this is a genitive of a root word.

So *when* was apparently the same or a closely related word, but *whence* is a holdover of an ancient genitive case which English doesn't have, any more, so the syntactical distinction that once clarified the relationship between *when* and *whence* has been lost.

Once upon a time, though, the relationship was clear:  one was a standard form of *when*, and the other was its genitive, or in other words, *when*, but applied to space, with respect to origin.

Answer (score 4):

There is no relation between the origin of *when* and *whence*.

The origin of the words reported by the NOAD are the following.
*Whence* comes from the Middle English *whennes*, from earlier *whenne* (from Old English *hwanon*, of Germanic origin) + *-s* (later respelled -ce to denote the unvoiced sound).
*When* comes from the Old English *hwanne*, *hwenne*, of Germanic origin.

Comment: So is [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whence) mistaken?  **whence**:  
c.1300, whennes, with adverbial genitive -s, from O.E. hwanone, related to hwænne (see [when](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/when)).

Comment: I don't know, but I can't help thinking there may be an etymological connection between *whence* and **hence**. And although the latter is primarily "spatial", it's also "logical" *(hence=thus)*, and "temporal" *(henceforth, etc.)*.

Comment: Should probably add some kind of citation.